# Pausing and serializing an AVAssetExportSession

Tags: cocoa, serialization, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to export several minutes of video in an AVAssetExportSession and it's taking a long time. My ideal way of doing this is pausing the AVAssetExportSession when the app closes and resuming it when the app reopens. Is there any way to pause an AVAssetExportSession, save its state, and reload it later?