# How to pause and resume AVAssetExportSession while exporting a video composition

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, avasset, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to export a rotated video using AVAssetExportSession, and want to pause and resume AVAssetExportSession at button click.

```
    var exportSession = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) 
    exportSession?.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exportSession?.outputURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    exportSession?.videoComposition = videoComposition
    var exportProgress: Float = 0
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Export Progress Queue")

    queue.async(execute: {() -> Void in

        while exportSession != nil {
            exportProgress = (exportSession?.progress)!
            print("current progress == \(exportProgress)")
            }
            sleep(1)
        }
    })

    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        if exportSession?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed {
            print("Failed \(exportSession?.error?.localizedDescription)")
             exportSession = nil

        } else if exportSession?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
            exportSession = nil
           VideoSave.saveVideoToPhotoLibrary(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: videoPath), error: nil)
       }

    })
```

let suppose if a video whose export progress is completed 50%. So I pause its export process at 50% then resume it again. It should resume from 50% where it was paused before.

Comment: I do not think `AVAssetExportSession` has such kind of facility. Did not find any `pause/resume` method in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession).

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812343/pausing-and-serializing-an-avassetexportsession) already asked two years ago.

Comment: It might help us to understand why you are doing this; could you tell us? If you are trying to do this if someone shuts down the app and restart this later - you can't really pause this. You'd have to restart it. But, you do have time AFTER the user shuts down the app to finish stuff and this can be done in the `AppDelegate.swift`. If you have other reasons, there may be workarounds. We'd need to know your implications.